# FadeOut doesn't allow appearance of error alert anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following HTML code:

```
<div style="width:235px; " id="ErrorAlert" ng-hide="ErrorAlert">
     <alert type="danger">User's email is duplicated!</alert>
</div>
```

JS to set alert timeout is,

```
 $scope.ErrorAlert = false;
 setTimeout(function () {
      $('#ErrorAlert').fadeOut('slow');
 }, 2000);   //2 second
```

The problem is that after the time passes and alert is disappeared, If I call the alert again, it does not appear. Maybe because time out was set and it has already expired.

How can I make the alert reappear even if time out has already passed on a previous event.

Comment: The timeout is irrelevant, it's what is ostensibly *showing* the alert that's not, well, re-showing it (`ngShow` maybe?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) will use a class (`class="ng-hide"`) to hide your element whereas `jQuery.fadeOut()` will write an inline style attribute with `display: none`.

Your browser will always give priority to inline style so Angular will remove this class but object will stay hidden because of inline style.

When you set `$scope.ErrorAlert = true;` also use jQuery to remove inline styles or call `.show()` method.

One solution :

```
$scope.ErrorAlert = false;
 setTimeout(function () {
      $('#ErrorAlert').fadeOut('slow', function () {
          $scope.ErrorAlert = true;
          // $('#ErrorAlert').show();
          $('#ErrorAlert').removeAttr('styles');
      });
 }, 2000);   //2 second
```

May be instead of `$('#ErrorAlert').show();` try using `$('#ErrorAlert').removeAttr('styles')` ... because your object will probably not hide since he has `display: block;` inline and `ng-hide` class to hide ... :D

Comment: Shouldn't the call be to `.addClass('ng-hide')` and `.removeClass('ng-hide')`? I would think layering classes and inline styles that do the same thing is non-optimal.

Comment: ng-hide is completely managed by Angular so ng-hide is based only your model (here `ErrorAlert` variable), but jQuery override everything and do not look at angular stuff ... you basically use two different way to hide your element and they are in conflict.

Comment: Keep in mind, I'm not the OP. I also don't know Angular that well, so the point I'm making is not to use jQuery to show/hide, but try to use Angular's `ng-` processors instead.

Comment: @sebastienbarbier where and how to use the .show() can you help arrange than answer in plunker?

Comment: I updated my answer can you give a try ? The problem here is using jQuery to fadeout ... some CSS transition would be more appropriate, and may be ng-animate could help but never used it ... :(

Comment: Yes, I gave it a try, it shows the alert again and again without my click event.

Comment: Like an infinite loop ? Will be difficult for me to help you without looking at your structure, but you got an idea of what's wrong and what to look at so you should be able to debug it. Let me know how it goes ^^.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to re-toggle using this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-click="">
  <p>Hello {{name}}! <button type='button' id='ShowAlert'>Show Alert</button></p>
  <div style="width: 235px;" id="ErrorAlert" ng-show="ErrorAlert">
    <alert type="danger">User's email is duplicated!</alert>
  </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.ErrorAlert = false;

  $('#ShowAlert').on('click', function(){
    $scope.ErrorAlert = true;

    setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.ErrorAlert = false;
      });
    }, 2500);
  });

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/qEUTmgfYUhQYMEdRAG3z?p=preview

So, use your `$scope.ErrorAlert` to toggle the view, but make sure and trigger the change in `$scope.ErrorAlert` by telling Angular it's happened.

Here's what I assume is an Angular-y way of doing a dismiss button:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-click="">
  <p>
    Hello {{name}}! 
    <button type='button' id='ShowAlert' ng-click="ErrorAlert = !ErrorAlert">Show Alert</button>
  </p>
  <div style="width: 235px;" id="ErrorAlert" ng-show="ErrorAlert">
    <alert type="danger">User's email is duplicated!</alert>
    <button type='X' ng-click="ErrorAlert = false">Close</button>
  </div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.ErrorAlert = false;

  $('#ShowAlert').on('click', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.ErrorAlert = false;
      });
    }, 2500);
  });

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OEdr2OWPV11hVnYSVRMc?p=preview